# Reading INI file using Boost Property Tree when value section does not exist

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm using `Boost.PropertyTree` to read INI file:

```
read_ini( "myIni.ini", pt );
string s=pt.get<std::string>("Section1.value1");
```

If section doesn't contain `value1` record then Boost raises exception.

How to read INI file in an elegant way and give a default value to `s` in case `Section1.value1` does not exist?

Comment: I guess you mean that you use the [Boost Property tree library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/property_tree.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Boost.Optional`:

```
s = pt.get_optional<std::string>("Section1.value1").get_value_or("default");
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                     ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You should state which boost library you are referring to in your question. The answer is found in [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/accessing.html).

You can use `get_optional`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using what the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/property_tree/accessing.html#property_tree.accessing.three_ways_of_getting_data) calls the "throwing version" of `get()`. However, there is also a "default value" version which takes an extra argument -- the default value. As a bonus, the type specification is usually not needed since the type is deduced from the default value.

If the default value is `"default"` then you simply use

```
string s=pt.get("Section1.value1", "default");
```

The other answers mention the use of `get_optional()`, but this isn't exactly what you want since the value of `string s` is not optional (even though `Section.value1` in the INI file is optional).